# Using sed to replace curly braces

Tags: bash, sed

I am parsing some json data and I am in need of removing both beginning and ending curly braces, {}. I am using sed to perform this operation, but from what I can tell curly braces perform special functionality in sed and escaping them doesn't seem to be working. Here are a couple examples of what I have tried. I really could use a working regular expression. Thanks in advance!

First thing I tried that doesn't work.

```
sed 's/\{\}//g'
```

Some redone code from an answer I found here.

```
sed 's/\(\{\|\}\)//g'
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove all `{`'s and `}`'s or a string `{}`? It's better to include example input and desired output for clarity.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I am removing them individually, from various points in the data. There is often no space between the braces and what comes before it as well if that is important.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use `tr` for that:

```
tr -d '{}' < file.json
```

---

With `sed` it should be:

```
sed 's/[{}]//g' file.json
```

`[{}]` is a character class that means `{` or `}`.

If you want to change the file in place pass the `-i` option to `sed` or use the [`sponge`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) tool from [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/). I like it because it is generic, meaning it will work with any command regardless if it supports in place editing or not:

```
sed 's/[{}]//g' file.json | sponge file.json
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Out of curiousity, whats the syntax to remove braces?

Comment: It is `sed 's/[][]//g'` :)

Comment: @hek2mgl Good stuff, now I have my data exactly how I want it.

Comment: Cool Please also check my update! Actually this is a job for `tr`!